# Make vba excel function dynamic with the reference cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have written a code which creates a sumproduct of two range.... But I want the final answer to change when the reference ranges whose sumproduct is been calculated is changed

```
p = 1
For p = 1 To 12
ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow + 2, 31 + p).Formula = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(Range(Cells(3, 31 + p), Cells(LastRow, 31 + p)), Range(Cells(3, 6 + p), Cells(LastRow, 6 + p)))
Next p
```

for example in the above sheet the sumproduct result is shown in the lastrow+2 th row and from column 31 to 42, but when i change the reference cells the answer doesnt change 
how to make my end result dynamic with the input

Comment: with `.Formula` you need to add a formula like you would add it manually into the Excel cell like `.Formula("=SumProduct(…)")` so the formula is recalculated by Excel automatically. To get the address of a range and use it in your formula use the [Range.Address method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx).

Comment: how can we loop using such representation.. please help me with this.

Comment: fill in the formula for `p = 1` e.g `Cells(LastRow + 2, 32).Formula = "…"` and afterwards copy that cell right into the other cells would be an easy approach so no loop is needed: `Cells(LastRow + 2, 32).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(LastRow + 2, 32), Cells(LastRow + 2, 43))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `.Formula` you need to add a formula like you would add it manually into the Excel cell like `.Formula("=SumProduct(…)")` so the formula is recalculated by Excel automatically. To get the address of a range and use it in your formula use the [Range.Address method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx).

---

Instead of a loop just fill out the formula for the first cell `p = 1`

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow + 2, 32).Formula = "=SumProduct(" & Range(Cells(3, 32), Cells(LastRow, 32)).Address(False, False) & ", " & Range(Cells(3, 7), Cells(LastRow, 7)).Address(False, False) & ")"
```

and then auto fill that cell right into the others (up to `p = 12`)

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow + 2, 32).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(LastRow + 2, 32), Cells(LastRow + 2, 43))
```

After that the sum product automatically recalculates if you change any values.

Comment: Thank you for investing your precious time